# LWC compiler doesn't works in appropriate way

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

We are creating a LWC, we finished it and now we have a problem. It is a widget that stays and lives in opportunities inside Sales tab of Salesforce, it has HTML, CSS and JS implementation. The problem is that it sometimes works in some tenants, debugging it and seeing the console of the browser we noticed that the code is different, and it says that was compiled using the LWC Compiler (on the working tenants), but in the non-working tenants the code appears just like we wrote it, it seems that the compiler doesn't works, but we aren't sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you [enable debug mode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.debug_mode_enable), you'll see your components source in mydomain/components/c/component.js, while if you disable it, you'll see a minified version, instead.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, I already have the debug mode enable in both tenants (working and non-working), but the modules/c folder only appears on the working tenant.